# Migrating qrcode scanner from Mobile vision to ML kit

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I have a small test app to scan a QR code. It was working with Mobile vision but I would like to migrate to ML kit.`

What is working: camera starts with a live preview.
What is not working: if I point to a qr code, it doesn't trigger the task.isSuccessful

If I take out the if(task.isSuccessful()) then immediately after starting the camera, I get the error
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
in task.getResult()

This is my code, the qr scanner is in a seperate Activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanner;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScannerOptions;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.camera.CameraSourceConfig;
import com.google.mlkit.vision.camera.CameraXSource;
import java.util.List;

public class ScanQRcodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CameraXSource cameraXSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_q_rcode);
        PreviewView preview = findViewById(R.id.view);
        BarcodeScanner barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE).build());
        CameraSourceConfig cameraSourceConfig = new CameraSourceConfig.Builder(this, barcodeScanner, task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                final List<Barcode> qrCode = task.getResult();
                if (qrCode.size() != 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.putExtra("QR", qrCode.get(0).getDisplayValue());
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                    cameraXSource.stop();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }).setFacing(CameraSourceConfig.CAMERA_FACING_BACK).build();
        cameraXSource = new CameraXSource(cameraSourceConfig, preview);
        cameraXSource.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I forgot that the first task is just the DetectionTaskCallback. Meaning that is when the DetectionTask is received. The lambda hides this a bit. So inside I need to start a task to process an image with the barcodescanner.

So the final code (without lambda's gives:):

```
    CameraXSource cameraXSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_q_rcode);
        PreviewView preview = findViewById(R.id.view);
        BarcodeScannerOptions barcodeScannerOptions = new BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder().setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE).build();
        BarcodeScanner barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(barcodeScannerOptions);
        CameraSourceConfig cameraSourceConfig = new CameraSourceConfig.Builder(this, barcodeScanner, new DetectionTaskCallback<List<Barcode>>() {
            @Override
            public void onDetectionTaskReceived(@NonNull Task<List<Barcode>> task) {
                task = barcodeScanner.process(InputImage.fromBitmap(preview.getBitmap(), 0));
                task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Barcode>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull List<Barcode> barcodes) {
                        if (barcodes.size() != 0) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.putExtra("QR", barcodes.get(0).getDisplayValue());
                            ScanQRcodeActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                            cameraXSource.stop();
                            ScanQRcodeActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }).setFacing(CameraSourceConfig.CAMERA_FACING_BACK).build();
        cameraXSource = new CameraXSource(cameraSourceConfig, preview);
        cameraXSource.start();
```

Comment: I think it is a big waste doing a `preview.getBitmap()` for every single frame. This drags down the performance of your app drastically. A nice example of how it should be done properly can be found here (not mine): https://github.com/irhammuch/android-mlkit-barcodescanner/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/irhammuch/example/mlkitbarcode/MainActivity.java